# expression using grep is giving all zeros

Tags: bash, scripting

So I have an expression that I want to extract some lines from a text and count them. I can grep them as follows:

```
$ cat medsCounts_totals.csv | grep -E 'NumMeds": 0' | wc -l
```

Which is fine. Now I want to loop over with the string ...

```
$ for i in {0..10}; do expr="NumMeds\": $i"; echo $expr; done
```

However, when I try to use `$expr`

```
for i in {0..10}; do expr="NumMeds:\" $i"; cat medsCounts_totals.csv | grep -E "$expr" | wc -l ; done
```

I get nothing. How do I solve this problem in an elegant manner?

Comment: In the last case you swap the position of the quote and the colon

Comment: Can you your sample input with expected output.

Comment: Yes, really bad mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a typo in

```
for i in {0..10}; do expr="NumMeds:\" $i"; cat medsCounts_totals.csv | grep -E "$expr" | wc -l ; done
```

it should be

```
"NumMeds\": $i"
```